# Wants to filter and copy from sheet2 but without activating sheet2

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter, excel-tables, listobject

I have a excel file wherein 2 sheets are their.
From Sheet1, wants to filter data in sheet2 table and copy and paste filtered data in sheet1 A1 cell.
Is is possible get it done through sheet1 itself without activating or selecting sheet2

I had written code but filter it is working only when sheet2 is selected

```
Sub Test()

On Error Resume Next

With Sheets("Sheet2")

    .ShowAllData

    .ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=(Rows("2").Find("Model").Column), Criteria1:= _
        "=DZIRE", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Ertiga"
End With
    
    Range("Table1[Outlet Name],Table1[Supplier Category],Table1[Model]").Copy


    ActiveSheet.Paste


End Sub
```

Comment: Try using `.Rows("2").Find(   ` (a dot is missing). What sheet does this range refer: `Range("Table1[Outlet Name],Table1[Supplier Category],Table1[Model]").Copy`? `If Sheet2`, the code line must be places inside the `With ... End With`, but having a dot in front (`Range("Table1[Outlet Name],...`.

Comment: I had made changes but table data didn't get filtered as per criteria...    

Sub Test()

On Error Resume Next

With Sheets("Sheet2")

    .ShowAllData

    .ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter.Rows("2").Find("Model").Column , Criteria1:= _
        "=DZIRE", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Ertiga"

    .Range("Table1[Outlet Name],Table1[Supplier Category],Table1[Model]").Copy

End With

    ActiveSheet.Paste


End Sub

Comment: You did not ask about that, I'm afraid... Do you mean that **if you select that specific sheet** and run the code it works, and if you don't, it doesn't? And **do not post code in comments**. Please, edit your question and adapt there the code, explaining what it does/does not...

Comment: If I run macro from sheet1, filter doesn't apply in sheet 2 table and copy all data.
When I rung macro from Sheet2, filter get applied in table and copy only filtered data.

Comment: Please, comment the line `On Error Resume Next` and see if an error is raised. I suppose that "DZIRE" and "Ertiga" are simple strings. Is that correct? And why did not edit your question and place the modified code instead of existing?

Comment: And replace `.ShowAllData` with `If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData`...

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Filtered Excel Table Columns

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim sTbl As ListObject: Set sTbl = sws.ListObjects("Table1")

    With sTbl.AutoFilter        
        If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData ' remove previous filter
    End With
    
    sTbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=sTbl.ListColumns("Model").Index, _
        Criteria1:="DZIRE", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Ertiga"
    
    Dim svrg As Range: Set svrg = sTbl.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    sTbl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

    Dim srg As Range
    Set srg = Union(Intersect(svrg, sTbl.ListColumns("Outlet Name").Range), _
        Intersect(svrg, sTbl.ListColumns("Supplier Category").Range), _
        Intersect(svrg, sTbl.ListColumns("Model").Range))
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'dws.Cells.Clear ' clear the whole worksheet
    
    srg.Copy dws.Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked and my problem get resolved